# PuTTY tunnel - Network Error: Software caused connection abort

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, tunnel

I have another variant of the "Network Error: Software caused connection abort".  I can reliably connect to a Linux box and get the shell, but as soon as I try to connect to a tunneled local port, the main connection drops.

I can successfully connect to an identical tunnel from another machine configured the exact same way, except it's running Windows 7 SP1 Professional (instead of SP1 Enterprise), and the login has admin privileges.  The tunnel definition is from local port 80 to remote port 80 (on the same Linux box), and I see it trigger two connections (in PuTTY's event log) the instant I open http://localhost/ in a local browser, but the main PuTTY connection immediately drops (e.g., a continuously scrolling output in its window stops) and the browser eventually times out.  I tried moving the local port above 1024 (to 8080, and opening http://localhost:8080/), but it has the exact same effect.

I do have all TCP keepalive options turned on, but they have no effect on this behavior.

Any ideas?